# invalid number format model oracle error inserting a char

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01481

I am trying to create an Oracle stored procedure that simply inserts a row into a table.  There is a column in the table (MEAS_IND) that is type char(1 byte) and cannot be null.  When I try to insert any one character into the column/table I get the error:

```
ORA-01481: invalid number format model
ORA-06512: at "IFDC.PKG_FIELD_ASSISTANT", line 326
ORA-06512: at line 3
01481. 00000 -  "invalid number format model"
*Cause:    The user is attempting to either convert a number to a string
           via TO_CHAR or a string to a number via TO_NUMBER and has
           supplied an invalid number format model parameter.
*Action:   Consult your manual.
```

I have tried inserting ' ', 'N' and to_char(' ').  There are other columns that cannot be null and seem to work fine.  When I comment out MEAS_IND I get the error that it cannot be null, so I am assuming that the other columns are fine. Here is the code:

```
INSERT INTO myTable
          (
            cont_id
            , cms_uid
            , dwr_dt
            , prj_nbr
            , ln_itm_nbr
            , loc_seq_nbr
            , loc_instld
            , vend_id
            , rpt_qty
            , itm_cd
            , last_modfd_uid
            , last_modfd_dt
            , catg_nbr
            , rmrks_id, plan_pg_ref_nbr, ref_doc, fr_sta_itm, fr_sta_dstnc, fr_sta_offst_t, fr_sta_offst_dstnc
            , to_sta_itm, to_sta_dstnc, to_sta_offst_t, to_sta_offst_dstnc, meas_ind
          )
       VALUES
          (
            pContractId
            , pUSER_ID
            , pDRW_DATE
            , pProject_num
            , pPLN
            , vMaxLocSeq
            , pLocation
            , pVend_id
            , pAmount
            , pItemCode
            , pUSER_ID
            , to_number(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD')
            , vCatigoryNumber
            , ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 0, ' ', 0
            , ' ', 0, ' ', 0, ' '
          ) ;
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `to_number(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD')`, do this:

```
to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMMDD'))
```

Better yet, if it's not too late in the project then change the `last_modfd_dt` column to a `DATE` type. The `DATE` type will include the date *and* the time of day (hours, minutes, seconds but no fractional seconds). If you just want the date without the time, set it as `trunc(sysdate)`.

Comment: Found the answer:  It was the to_number convertion

Comment: Could the down-voter please explain the reason for the vote? No hard feelings; just if there's something wrong I want to fix it. Thanks.